# Generate a new form

Tags: forms

I want to insert a form element (`type = 'select'`) into an EXISTING page.

Normally we would use define a new page with a page callback, the page callback would then call `drupal_get_form`.

In this case, the page is being generated by views and I want to simply insert a form field within `hook_views_pre_view` .

Not having success so far with `drupal_get_form` or `drupal_build_form`.

`drupal_build_form` is advertised as returning a rendered form. But doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Where do you want to insert the field?  Can you use a block?

Comment: No... as I indicated, I want to insert a form into an existing page that is being generated by Views. I am using hook_views_pre_view to prepend dynamic data into the output. It is within that hook that I want to insert the form. I'm already using renderable arrays to insert various items...

I simply want to add a form.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can achieve by the following steps

- You can embed a **node creation form** inside a VIEW

  - Either in **VIEW Header** or you can created a **new VIEW and attach it to your VIEW**
- For this example I am embedding inside **Views Header**. Embedding inside **Views Header** will be the better options. Click to **Add Views Header**

  [image]
- Select Global: Text area

  [image]
- Add the PHP code and don't forget to change the **Text Format to PHP**

  [image]
- PHP code

  `<?php 
      module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
      $node_form = node_add('node_type');
      print drupal_render($node_form);
  ?>`

Note :

- Don't forget to replace **node_type** in the PHP code.
- Use **hook_form_alter** for node form redirection, as after the node creation the form will redirect to node detail page. If you want to redirect to your page then use `$form_state['redirect'] = 'mycustompage';` [reference](https://drupal.org/node/1074616#comment-4218548)
- Enable **PHP Filter** module using **admin/modules**

[image]

- Set the **Permissions** for this module by enabling "Administrator" for **Execute PHP Code** as follows:

[image]

Comment: That would probably work.